# jquery dialog appears on top of menu

Tags: jquery, menu, dialog, load, z-index

I have a jQuery dialog that loads on document.ready with a zIndex of 800. On this page I also have a menu that has a zIndex of 999. However, when I display the dialog and then use the menu, the dialog appears on top of the menu when, based on z-index, it should be below it. If I configure the dialog in the window.load event the menu / dialog ordering is correct. This doesn't make sense to me since the menu content is already loaded into the DOM prior to the dialog being configured. Any ideas? Thanks. Have to take my word that the menu is 9999.  You can see the page at http://qa.ncgov-2012.nc.gov/maps/#.
Here is config for the dialog:

```
$('#lyrPanel').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-custom" id="lyrsButton"></span> Map Options',
    height: 215,
    width: 240,
    minWidth: 195,
    minHeight: 150,
    maxWidth: 240,
    maxHeight: 215,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    zIndex: 800,
    stack: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: {
        of: $map,
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top',
        offset: '39'
    }
});
```

Comment: code code code code code

Comment: What happens if you remove or comment out the code block that follows `This is supposed to fix the IE7 zIndex issues`?

Answer (score 0):

Give jquery stacking elements a try instead of having z-indexes that spin out of control.
http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/

Answer (score -1):

zindex only works on positioned elements (absolute, relative)

Comment: jquery dialogs in general are positioned and the menu is as well.